# Selenium Web driver script running in alphabetical order of method name on TestNG. What is the way to run it in a specific sequence

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I have to run my scripts in specific order let say :-
1)Login 
2)Add Profile 
3)Edit Profile
4)Delete profile

But when I execute my script it is executing alphabetically not as the desired flow.

What can be done to run testcases in desired sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize you tests:

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void LoginTest() {}

@Test(priority=2)
public void AddProfileTest() {}
```

In this case tests will run according theirs priority (lower priorities will be scheduled first).

Or you can use dependsOnMethods and dependsOnGroups:

```
@Test(groups = "group1")
public void LoginTest() {}

@Test(groups = "group1")
public void AddProfileTest() {}

@Test(dependsOnGroups = "group1")
public void EditProfile() {}
```

In this case EditProfile test will only run after LoginTest() and AddProfileTest() have completed successfully.

Or you can specify order of tests run in testng.xml.

See documentation: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Thanks Andreyla I am able to execute the test by prioritizing my test. I found it a simple approch to run the testcase in the desired sequence.

Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Could you please mark question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML to make your methods run in an order.

For Example

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">


<suite name="ur suite name">

  <test name="test_name" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="packagename.class name">

        <methods>

         <include name="method1"/>
         <include name="method2"/>


        </methods>


      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
`:
```